# codigo para url amigable, verificar url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

tengo un simple códio para realizar urls amigables, lo pongo a continuación :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^acceder_usuario index.php?action=login
```

**Con este código pues pasaría de una dirección del tipo :**

**dominio/index.php?action=login** a una dirección **dominio/acceder_usuario**

Si por ejemplo pongo algo diferente a **acceder_usuario**, da error como es lógico y aquí tengo 2 cuestiones porque he probado de todo y es hacer o verificar que la url total sea tal cual y sino tomar acciones.

Por ejemplo veo que si pongo : URL/acceder_usuario?options=ok , la URL sigue funcionando, lo cual no me interesa, es decir, que no pudiese cargar sería lo ideal o se redireccionase a otro lado, dado qeu sino tocaría hacerlo mediante código php, he probado todo tipo de opciones en htaccess y ninguna verifica la URL total, entonces mi idea sería que si por ejemplo la URL estrictamente no fuese URL/acceder_usuario, redireccionase a otro lado, o bien ya saliese la típica página de error que es la que debería de salir tipo 404.

Pasa que hacer algo con htaccess es bastante confuso y no acabas de ver un manual donde explique las cosas bien, también revise el oficial y la verdad hay cosas que no están bien reflejadas.

Esa sería mi cuestión, un cordial saludo y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder usar el valor de la variable action en el get como url amigable yo tengo esto:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$  index.php?action=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Options +Indexes
```

Para hacerlo como lo estas haciendo ahora mismo, es decir, si la variable action es login, que la url sea acceder_usuario, tendrías que hacer una linea por cada página para decirle al htaccess que mostrar según lo que ponga en el action.

De la forma que tienes arriba, cogería el resultado del action y lo mostraría como url. Con cambiar tu action a action=acceder_usuario ya tendrías la url de la página igual.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Por ejemplo con lo qeu me has puesto si pongo el código funciona al disponer lo equivalente a action que sería login y se carga, pero si pongo por ejemplo una barra del tipo URL/login/ se carga una versión incorrecta de la web, cómo se puede evitar eso ? por otro lado en la parte de mi pregunta indicaba también como se podría evitar que en la URL se cargase algo más que no fuese URL/login, y si apareciese algo además, se redireccionase al index solo como un error o que no es la url que yo quiero que sea la única y correcta, un saludo y de nuevo muchas gracias

Comment: Eso tendrías que controlarlo desde la vista index.php. Dependiendo de la lógica de tu página se haría de una manera u otra. Por ejemplo, si en tu página cargas en archivo u otro dependiendo del resultado del action, primero podrías establecer un comprobador que mire si existe el archivo del action, y si no, muestre una páguna de error. Por ejemplo: If(file_exist(''vistas/'.$GET['action'].".php")) { //codigo } else { echo "error, no existe la pagina.";}. Dependiendo de tu lógica, tendrás que comprobar que existe esa vista de una manera u otra.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por todo, un saludo

Comment: Una pregunta más, para qué sirve esta linea RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L], si al quitarla sigue funcionando igual y lo del tema .php, gracias

Comment: Serviría para eliminar el .php de la vista

Comment: Ah ok gracias :)